# Вывод значений нескольких селектов на чистом JS

Tags: javascript

Нужно сделать вывод нескольких селектов для дальнейшего подсчета их значений.   Проблема: выводит несколько раз значение первого селекта.    Ответ желательно на чистом JavaScript.

```js
function calc() {
  document.getElementById('MB');
  var select = document.querySelector('select');
  console.log(select.value);
  document.getElementById('C');
  var select = document.querySelector('select');
  console.log(select.value);
}
```

```html
<select name="P" id="C">
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
<select name="M" id="MB">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button type="button" name="button" id="btn" onclick=calc()>BUTTON</button>
```

Comment: и что конкретно не получается? что Вы пробовали сделать сами?

Comment: @Bald Я извеняюсь если что, я новичок. document.getElementById('имя id') var select = document.querySelector('select') и можно вывести значение select.value Вопрос: как получить значение второго селекта если getElementById не помогает? Тоесть выводит два одинаковых значения

Comment: @Bald <select name="P" id="C">
 <option value="4">4</option>
 <option value="5">5</option>
 <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
<select name="M" id="MB">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button type="button" name="button" id="btn" onclick=calc()>BUTTON</button>
function calc() {
  document.getElementById('MB');
  var select = document.querySelector('select');
  console.log(select.value);
  document.getElementById('C');
  var select = document.querySelector('select');
  console.log(select.value);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем примере код не работал, так как Вы ожидаете по той причине, что `querySelector('select')` возвращает **первый** подходящий элемент из *дома*.
Для того что бы код заработал необходимо вот этот код:

```
document.getElementById('MB');
var select = document.querySelector('select');
```

заменить на:

```
var select = document.getElementById('MB');
```

Получение выбранного значения из выпадающего списка выглядит так:

```
var selectedValue = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
```

Рабочий пример ниже

```js
function calc() {
  var select = document.getElementById('MB');
  console.log(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value);
  select = document.getElementById('C');
  console.log(select.options[select.selectedIndex].value);
}
```

```html
<select name="P" id="C">
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
</select>
<select name="M" id="MB">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<button type="button" name="button" id="btn" onclick=calc()>BUTTON</button>
```